# recalculateFormulas() returns "System.HandledException: Script-thrown exception (System Code)" when Address has State selected

Tags: apex, formula-field, before-trigger, address, country-and-state

In trigger action BeforeInsert Quote, recalculateFormulas() returns this error "System.HandledException: Script-thrown exception (System Code)". It happens only when State is selected in Quote's standard Address field.

```
public void beforeInsert(List<Quote> newList){
    for(Quote qt :newList){
        qt.Sales_Org__c = '1008';
    }
    //recalculate formula fields based on sales org
    List<FormulaRecalcResult> results = Formula.recalculateFormulas(newList); 
}
```

Any idea why recalculateFormulas() triggers error only when State selected in Address?
Is there workaround to get updated formula field before inserting record?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community. Can you use [edit] to show a reproducible test case - this would include the relevant formulas